# iOS - NSJSONSerialization: Unable to convert data to string around character

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization

I'm getting this error while parsing JSON:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unable to convert data to string around character 73053.) UserInfo=0x1d5d8250 {NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 73053.}
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

**ADDED**
As it says in error report, the parser can't go through the character at position 73053, which is "ø" in my JSON response. As far as I know characters like Ø,Å,Æ etc. shouldn't be a problem for json parsers?

Comment: Did you check the response string and can you show it

Comment: Check to make sure your response is valid JSON

Comment: I have checked my JSON on JSON validator, looks like it is valid

Comment: Could you post your response?  Googling that error is showing results of people who have valid JSON, but their response is improperly formed. ex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282771/cocoa-error-3840-nsjsonserialization and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282771/cocoa-error-3840-nsjsonserialization

Comment: Maybe you should post the snippet of JSON surrounding the problem characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that the data you're parsing is actually valid JSON (and not just 'nearly' JSON). That error is known to occur when you have a different data format that can't be parsed as JSON. See for example:

[iOS 5 JSON Parsing Results in Cocoa Error 3840](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174130/ios-5-json-parsing-results-in-cocoa-error-3840)

Do you have a top-level container in your JSON too? An array or dictionary. Example:

```
{ "response" : "Success" }
```

**Update**

JSON's default encoding is UTF-8. Special/exotic characters aren't a problem for UTF-8, but please ensure that your server is returning its content properly encoded as UTF-8. Also, have you done anything to tell your JSON interpretter to use a different encoding?

If your JSON is coming from a web service, put the URL into this page to see what it has to see about the encoding:

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Yep, one needs to assure that the character encoding being sent is identical to the one expected by the parser.  A conflict in DBCS encoding schemes is very likely the problem here.

Comment: Accepting your answer with a little delay :-) Solved the problem by encoding an output string with UTF-8.

Comment: Helps me a lot! Sometimes server side may callback us with GBK encoding thus may cause this problem.In my condition, I have noticed the data encoding is GBK, so I manually convert the encoding to NSUTF8.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, I have the same problem with encoding issue and got the above error. I got the NSData from server as `encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`. So I had to convert it to UTF8 before parsing it using NSJSONSerialization.

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSString *iso = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d1 encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSData *dutf8 = [iso dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dutf8 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
```

Comment: hello how are able to see which encoding is being sent back ? in your case it was NSISOlating1stringEncoding, how can I figure out for mine what is being sent back ?

Answer (score 7):

**Switf 3**

```
let responseStrInISOLatin = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.isoLatin1)
guard let modifiedDataInUTF8Format = responseStrInISOLatin?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
      print("could not convert data to UTF-8 format")
      return
 }
do {
    let responseJSONDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: modifiedDataInUTF8Format)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5:**

Yes, i got the same error while parsing JSON data.

Solution : You have to first convert response data into String and then convert that Sting to Data using UTF8 encoding before decoding.

```
let utf8Data = String(decoding: responseData, as: UTF8.self).data(using: .utf8)
```